# Problems with screen

Tags: unity, screen

On the screen appear black line and the screen sometimes freezes and flashes. When a right screenshot of the screen or record desktop turns on normally. This does not appear on Windows 8 CP and Ubuntu 2D and other themes for Ubuntu. How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! As it stands, your question may need a little more information  in order for it to be answered. If you are not technically savvy don't worry, just add as much information as you can, can you provide a screenshot so that you can get an answer (and a good one at that).

Comment: I already do that.

Comment: Have a read through this http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work

Comment: It is fixed after update Unity to 5.8.

Comment: All of problems are Unity version. That is bug fixed in Unity 5.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bug was fixed in the Unity 5.8 according to ZDroid:

> All of problems are Unity version. That is bug fixed in Unity 5.8.

– ZDroid Dec 28 '12 at 12:15

Comment: Yes... that's true.